# Smooth function on a compact

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth with $M$ compact. Show that for at least two distinct points in $M$ the differential of $f$ is zero.

So my thoughts were that $f$ should be constant at two different points, but i do not see how this follows from the fact that M should be compact.

Comment: What can you say about the set $f(M)$?

Comment: That it is a closed interval, so is it that the inverse of the 2 endpoints has a differential which is zero?

Comment: If you don't assume your manifolds connected, it need not be an interval. But that doesn't matter (as long as $\dim M > 0$). Indeed, the differential vanishes at (local) maxima or minima.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have 1 more question though. Does this use that f is continuous or does f need to be smooth.

From what i would think if f is smooth then f(compact)=closed so therefore the local minima/maxima still make the differential vanish.

Comment: If $f$ is only assumed continuous, the differential need not exist anywhere. Continuity is used for the existence of maxima and minima, smoothness is used for the existence of the differential there. We could do with a weaker premise than smoothness, mere differentiability suffices.